# continuity with lipschitz dertivative

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Can somone explain me what does it mean to say a "function is continously differentiable with a Lipschitz derivative near the limit point". I dont understand the technical jargoans.

Thanks

Comment: I believe the limit point is an end point and they are talking about a left or right handed derivative at the end point.  Would this definition fit the context of where you found this.

Comment: does it mean the same to have a lipscitz derivative and be lipscitz continous

Comment: No. In the former, the derivative is Lipschitz; in the latter, the function itself is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it as "the function $f$ is differentiable on its domain $D$, and $f^\prime$ is continuous on $D$; furthermore, there is a neighborhood $\mathcal{V}=[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]$ of the limit point $x_0$ such that $f^\prime$ is Lipschitz on $\mathcal{V}$".

(if $f$ is defined on some other space than $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, replace $\mathcal{V}=[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]$ by $\mathcal{V}=B(x_0,\epsilon)$)

Comment: to clarify, when you mean by f' is lipschitz on V, you mean the usual definition of lipschitz right, i.e. |f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|

Comment: Yes. Actually, when $C$ is not specified, it's ususally implicitly $1$.